# Print list object in column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, mediapipe

I have code which produces a CSV by printing as shown below

```
 array_all = {'Hand': [alldata], 'Pose':[keypoints], 'Face Pose': [face_position]}
        df = pd.DataFrame(
            array_all
        )
        df.to_csv('test.csv',
                  mode='w',
                  index=False,
                  header=True)
```

To give context to how these objects are created, here's the code for one of the objects, all objects are using the same structure

```
        face_position = []
        for data_point in results.face_landmarks.landmark:
            if 0.6 <= data_point.x < 0.8:
                face_position.append('Straight')
            else:
                face_position.append('Angled')

        print(face_position)
```

Here the face_landmarks refers to objects created from the mediapipe library(https://google.github.io/mediapipe/)

Currently my CSV prints like this
[image]

However, I want it to look like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line of code:

```
array_all = {'Hand': [alldata], 'Pose':[keypoints], 'Face Pose': [face_position]}
```

You are creating nested lists in each of your columns. Do not forget that `alldata`, `keypoints` and `face_position` are already lists.

Instead of the above, do the following:

```
array_all = {'Hand': alldata, 'Pose':keypoints, 'Face Pose': face_position}
```

Comment: Hey would really appreciate input on this question which is an extention of this one, thanks! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70057631/pandas-unnest-list-and-show-in-csv-each-array-value-in-a-cell-on-column-basis