# pandas - unnest list and show in csv each array value in a cell on column basis

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm preparing a dataset right now and I need it to have a certain format, such as this:

| Hand | Pose |
| --- | --- |
| No | Seating Back |
| Yes | Seating Back |
| No | Seating Back |
| Yes | Seating Back |
| No | Seating Back |
| Yes | Seating Back |

However, currently it's producing

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| Hand | ['No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No'] |
| Pose | ['Seating Back', 'Seating Back', 'Seating Back'] |

As you can see the values inside the array stored in one cell while I need it to be un-nested in a where one value occupies one cell.

My code:

```py
array_all = {'Hand': alldata, 'Pose': keypoints}
df = pd.Series(array_all)

# Keypoint detection
df.to_csv('test.csv',
          mode='w',
          header=True,
          index=True)
df.transpose()
```

To give context to the object, here is a snippet on one of them

```py
for data_point in results.face_landmarks.landmark:
    if 0.6 <= data_point.x < 0.8:
        face_position.append('Straight')
    else:
        face_position.append('Angled')
```

All arrays are being appended in this manner.

Comment: Thanks for adding the actual text. However, now `"Face Pose"` is missing

Comment: What's your desired output for the jagged data? Do you want to fill with the empty string or another sentinel value, or omit the rows missing data?

Comment: The jagged data should not have any kind of value, it can present itself as an empty string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating dataframe from a dictionary where entries have different lengths](/q/19736080/4518341). What worked for me is `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(array_all, orient='index').T` (from [dezzan's answer](/a/25217425/4518341)), which fills with `None`, which get converted to the empty string in the CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a `Series` instead of not a `DataFrame`. You *want* to create a `DataFrame`.

Change

```
df = pd.Series(array_all)
```

to

```
df = pd.DataFrame(array_all)
```

**Edit:** If you can't create a DataFrame because the arrays are not all of equal length, add empty strings to them until they all are as long as the longest of them, like this:

```py
array_all = {'Hand': alldata, 'Pose': keypoints, 'Face Pose': face_position}

# Pad the arrays with '' so that they are all the same length
max_size = max([len(array) for array in array_all.values()])
for array in array_all.values():
    array.extend([''] * (max_size - len(array)))

df = pd.DataFrame(array_all)
```

**Or,** a better solution:

```
array_all = {'Hand': alldata, 'Pose': keypoints, 'Face Pose': face_position}
array_all = {k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in array_all.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(array_all)
```

<sub>Last snippet partially credited to [@Jeff's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19736406/17242583).</sub>

Comment: Why are you using the empty string instead of say, `None`?

Comment: I'm assuming that Dinuli wants the rows to be empty. I'm assuming if I use `np.nan` or `None` they'll show up as `NaN` or `None` in the CSV file. Am I wrong?

Comment: Thank you, Your solution works to an extent, for making it in columns, however,  I'm still having the issue of unnesting the array where one value of the array populates one cell each rather than the entire array populating one cell (cell in CSV as shown at the bottom of the question above). Do you have any idea about this? Thank you!

Comment: Can you share a link to a screenshot?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0fud.png this is how it looks right now where the entire object just populates a cell

Comment: Are you doing it like `'Hand': [alldata]`? Don't do the brackets around `alldata` like that. Use my code exactly. It should do what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is unconventional but @user17242583, can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70069614/pandas-add-additional-column-to-an-existing-csv-file , appreciate it, Thanks!

Comment: It's unconventional to link other questions around link this, but it's ok here. Try @Corralien's solution.