# pandas - add additional column to an existing csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 files which need to populate the same csv file

To give context, currently, I have this code that prints a CSV in the desired way
code-1.py

Current Existing added:

```
array_all = {'Hand': alldata, 'Pose': face_position}
            array_all = {k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in array_all.items()}
            df = pd.DataFrame(array_all)

            df.to_csv('test.csv',
                        mode='w',
                        header=True,
                        index=False)
```

| Hand | Pose |
| --- | --- |
| No | Seating Back |
| No | Seating Back |

and now I have code-2.py

Column to add:

```
   df = pd.DataFrame(results)

    df.to_csv('test.csv',
              mode='a',
              header=True,
              index=False)
```

what I want this to do is add a column to the right
Desired Output:

| Hand | Pose | Eye |
| --- | --- | --- |
| No | Seating Back | Left |
| No | Seating Back | Right |

However, currently I am getting this,

Actual Output:

| Hand | Pose |
| --- | --- |
| No | Seating Back |
| No | Seating Back |
| 0 |  |
| Right |  |
| Left |  |

Basically, it is appending to the first column of the CSV
Also, it can be assumed that code-2.py  will be run immediately following code-1.py

Appreciate any ideas about this, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't append columns to a csv file without loading it entirely (however, you can append rows). Use `pd.concat`:

```
pd.concat([pd.read_csv('test.csv'), df], axis=1) \
  .to_csv('test.csv', header=True, index=False)
```

```
# test.csv before
Hand,Pose
No,Seating Back
No,Seating Back


# test.csv after
Hand,Pose,Eye
No,Seating Back,Left
No,Seating Back,Right
```

Answer (score 1):

with reference to @Corralien's answer

I additionally faced an issue where each additional append would record in a new column, as shown here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/08oTe.png

In order to mitigate this, I modified the given answer and created an additional csv and overwrote the csv using that, as shown below:

```
     pd.concat([pd.read_csv('test2.csv'), df], axis=1) \
            .to_csv('test.csv', header=True, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = (pd.read_csv("test.csv")).assign(Eyes=results)
df.to_csv('test.csv', header=True, index=False)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).